# Is there any way to switch a professional sword?

Tags: candy-box

I think that my question is pretty obvious. I currently have the sword of life, and I want to know if I can switch it to the sword of flames or the sword of summoning in any point of the game.

Comment: Protip: Sword of Summoning

Comment: Pro-ertip: Sword of Flames

Comment: Pro-esttip: Real pros use Sword of Life

Answer (score 4):

Later in the game, there are two additional swords you can receive. The Sword of LiFlameSummoning, which combines all three effects, and The Sword of Randomness, which kills everything except the final boss in one hit.

There is no way to switch between the original three swords other than loading an earlier save, or starting a new game.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but many would consider it hacking. If you're willing to do it, here's how, when using firefox.

1. Click tools in the little bar at the top of your screen.
2. Go to "Web Developer", and click "Toggle Tools".
3. Click the "Web Console" tab.
4. Click the bottom tab text typey thing.
5. Type sword.setName("Sword of Life") if you want a Sword of Life for example.

Comment: Just be careful to spell it correctly (e.g., make sure to include the *s* at the end of “Sword of Flames”), otherwise you could lose the sword (well, at least it won’t display in the inventory screen correctly).